# How to treat node that has no text?

Tags: xpath

There is an xml :

```
<mgns1:Champ_supplementaire>
    <mgns1:CODE_CS>3</mgns1:CODE_CS>
    <mgns1:VALEUR_CS />
</mgns1:Champ_supplementaire>
```

When trying to get :

`NodeList nodeliste_cs3 = (NodeList) xpath.evaluate( "//mgns1:Champ_supplementaire[mgns1:CODE_CS=3]/mgns1:VALEUR_CS",doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
...
Node node_cs3 = nodeliste_cs3.item(i);
list.add(node_cs3.getTextContent() + ";");`

I get NullPointerException ! So how to deal with node with no text ?

Answer (score 1):

You can explicitly add predicate to specify that *you want to select node only if it contains text*:

```
...mgns1:VALEUR_CS[normalize-space()]
```

Comment: I want to set "" as the value to add in the list if the node has no text . So how to achieve that ?

Comment: @pheromix , in XPath 2.0 you can try `for $x in //mgns1:Champ_supplementaire[mgns1:CODE_CS=3]/mgns1:VALEUR_CS return (if ($x/normalize-space()) then $x else '')`. In XPath 1.0 there is no such possibility, so I guess you would need to use programming language features...